# Stuck to curve meshes

Tags: modeling, mesh, 2d

I'm a beginner and I need to curve a mesh but I don't know how to proceed.

I reproduced this logo with 2D meshes but I don't know how to curve the yellow side.

[image]

I'm sure that's really easy but I'm stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by curve the yellow side? the yellow part already seems curved to me.

Comment: @person132 I think the pure white is the image logo beneath the mesh, which is grey

Comment: oh yeah you're right, i had it backwards